# Why am I getting "OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found..."?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I am using NUnit3 and trying to make use of `TestFixtureSource` in the following class hierarchy:

```
public class AtataTestFixtureData
{
    public static IEnumerable FixtureParams
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestFixtureData(new AtataConfigContainer
                                             {
                                                 AtataJsonConfig = new BaseAtataConfig()
                                             });
        }
    }
}

[TestFixtureSource(typeof(AtataConfigContainer), nameof(AtataTestFixtureData.FixtureParams))]
public class AtataTestsWithDbBase : OzCsTestsWithDbBase, IAtataAbpTests
{
    public AtataTestsWithDbBase()
    {

    }

    public AtataTestsWithDbBase(AtataConfigContainer aAtataConfigContainer)
    {
        AtataAbpTestsAdapter = AtataAbpTestsAdapter.Instance;
        AtataConfigContainer = aAtataConfigContainer;
    }
}

public class SomeSiteComAuTestsBase : AtataTestsWithDbBase
{
    public SomeSiteComAuTestsBase(AtataConfigContainer aAtataConfigContainer) : base(aAtataConfigContainer)
    {
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class IndexTests : SomeSiteComAuTestsBase
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Class constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public IndexTests(AtataConfigContainer aAtataConfigContainer) : base(aAtataConfigContainer)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void Get()
    {
        //Arrange

        //Act
        IndexPageObject indexPage = Go.To<IndexPageObject>();

        //Assert
    }
}
```

When I run IndexTests.Get() I get the exception `OneTimeSetUp: No suitable constructor was found` but according to `public IndexTests(AtataConfigContainer aAtataConfigContainer) : base(aAtataConfigContainer)` I have the needed constructor.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your `IndexTests` class has a constructor that takes parameters, but your `TestFixtureSource` is on a base class. The `TestFixtureSource` needs to be on your `IndexTests`. The `TestFixtureSource` attribute is not inherited.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Pretty sure I tried that but will confirm. Is there any workaround where a source can be on a base? Ultimate the tests themselves are for each page in the website Index etc. so having to add this to the descendant instead of the base makes the TestFixtureSource "less useful" (its configuration data) as DRY will have to continually be violated.

Comment: Adding TestFixtureSource to the descendant works. However any thoughts on a better way to do this? See above.